# GCE instance stopped working for 1 hour

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a GCE VM instance that went offline twice during the last 3 months for about an hour. In both instances, it came back up on its own. I wanted to know how I can figure out the problem so that it doesn't happen again.

- During this one hour, access to the instance through SSH was not possible and the website was down.
- I looked up online:

  1. some suggested the disk space might have been full which was not the case for me.
  2. Some suggested to look inside the Instance Logs, there wasn't anything out of ordinary.
- I know that my question is vague, however I need help to start looking for the source of the error. Essentially, I don't know what I am looking for and where I should look. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you look at the serial port logs from the instance when this happens? (Not sure if that's what you meant by "instance logs.")

Answer (score 1):

Is your VM using Local SSD?

From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#data_persistence :

"If the host system experiences a host error, Compute Engine attempts to preserve local SSD data, but it is only able to do so if the underlying drive recovers within 60 minutes."

Attempts to recover the data could explain your downtime.

Comment: Kevan thanks for your comment, however, I don't have a Local SSD. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the timing match with any of the Google Compute Engine or Google Cloud Networking incidents listed at https://status.cloud.google.com/summary?  If so it is possible you were affected by an outage.

Comment: David, Thanks for your answer. Yes, I already checked and there wasn't any incidents at that time.